# Always return false on authentication with hashed password

Tags: c#, security, hash, sha

Working with hashing password with sha256 and salt, my validate method always return false. While debugging I had noticed that on return it compare first 32 bite arrays with 64. And I don't know where I did mistake.

```
    public static byte[] Hash(string value, byte[] salt)
    {
        salt = new byte[64];
        using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(salt);
        }
        return Hash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value), salt);
    }

    public static byte[] Hash(byte[] value, byte[] salt)
    {
        var saltedValue = value.Concat(salt).ToArray();

        return new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(saltedValue);
    }

    public bool ConfirmPassword(string password)
    {
        var passwordSalt = new byte[64];
        using (var context = new DbConnection())
        {
            context.Connection.Open();
            context.SqlCommand.Connection = context.Connection;

            context.SqlCommand.CommandText = "select salt from users where name='test'";
            var reader = context.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                passwordSalt = reader["salt"] as byte[];
            }
        }
        var passwordHash = Hash(password, passwordSalt);

        return passwordHash.SequenceEqual(passwordSalt);
    }
```

**UPDATE**
So if I get it right:

```
public bool ConfirmPassword(string password)
{
    var userSalt = new byte[64];
    var temp = new byte[64];
    using (var context = new DbConnection())
    {
        context.Connection.Open();
        context.SqlCommand.Connection = context.Connection;

        context.SqlCommand.CommandText = "select password from users where name='test'";
        var reader = context.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            temp = reader["password"] as byte[];
        }
    }
    var passwordHash = Hash(password, userSalt);

    return passwordHash.SequenceEqual(temp);
}
```

But it also return me false

Comment: You compare the salt with hashed password. This is obviously always different.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič, I need to compare hash password from database with entered hashed password?

Comment: You have to get ta hashed password from the database. You read only 'salt' value (which is later used as salt for hashing the new password)

Comment: Where do you set userSalt? Is it the same as the one you used for storing the password?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič, you mean, usersalt from database? If yes, i didn't set it, password and salt are different. In reader i get hashed password and compare it with new generated hash from entered user password.

Comment: SHA256 is a secure hash function, but it is not designed for password verification.  Password verification should be slow, whereas SHA256 is fast.  Please read [this blog](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/06/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes.html), which has a section on *“Fixing” ASP.NET password hashing*.  That section tells you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume your password is "Hello" and your name="test".

### Storing

You need to generate a random salt. Than you can use the salt and the plain password ("Hello") with your Hash function. To save now the result in your database you **MUST** store the generated salt and the hashed password.

### Checking

Load the salt and hashed password from the database. Use again your Hash function with the user input (the plain password you want to check) and the salt from the database. Afterwards you can compare the result with the hashed password from the database. And thats it ...